# Can ServiceStack Redis MQ preserve a message for later processing if the first execution fails/crashes?

Tags: redis, servicestack

If I queue up a bunch of tasks into ServiceStack MQ, they are picked up by registered handlers for processing as expected.  However if my handler application exits during processing or crashes, the message seems to be gone for ever.

I see that it does support retries, and a dead letter queue, but are messages only retried if they explicitly throw and exception from the handler?

Is there any way to have the framework handle keeping the message around until a success result is returned from the handler?